# does having both www.sitename.com and www.sitename.com/index.php In site links affect SEO?

Tags: seo

I was told this by a coworker, and I was curious if this was true.  They requested I change any links on a site that point to the homepage as 'index.php', I'm assuming because they think it will treat the two different URLs (www.sitename.com  and www.sitename.com/index.php) as duplicate content. However, I don't think that this is the case. What say you, StackOverflow?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might, but the best way to avoid this (and any other duplicate content issues) is to use the [canonical link](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) tag

Answer (score 2):

Yes - it does.  I would recommend 301 redirecting index.php to /

Comment: how would you do that? they are both the same file.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer yes.

You should do a 301 to one of the two so search engines only see one page vs. a duplicate.  Also, you can create a [sitemap for Google](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40318).  See the [Google Web Master](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633) site on 301 Redirects.  And here is a google page that describes [301's and duplicate content](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359).